# Wall Cracking Detection using Aforge

Tags: c#, aforge

I'm trying to detect wall cracking using Aforge, below is my code.
how can i highlight the cracking inside the original picture, and if there are better code for detecting wall cracking?
and how should i measure the length of width of the crack?[Left hand side is the original image, right hand side is the "crack" i detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIpuD.png)

```
 Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)org.Clone();
        // create grayscale filter 
        Grayscale filter_grayscale = new Grayscale(0.299, 0.587, 0.114);
        temp = filter_grayscale.Apply(temp);
        // create thresholding filter
        Threshold filter = new Threshold(120);
        filter.ApplyInPlace(temp);
        // create filter
        CannyEdgeDetector filter_edge = new CannyEdgeDetector();
        filter_edge.ApplyInPlace(temp);

        // create filter
        Invert filter_invert = new Invert();
        filter_invert.ApplyInPlace(temp);
        // create and configure the filter
        FillHoles filter_hole = new FillHoles();
        filter_hole.MaxHoleHeight = 20;
        filter_hole.MaxHoleWidth = 20;
        filter_hole.CoupledSizeFiltering = false;
        filter_hole.ApplyInPlace(temp);

        pictureBox2.Image =temp;
```